# Multiprocessing pool with parameters that cannot be serialized

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pool

The pool function of multiprocessing pickles all the parameters that are passed into it and then recreates them in the pool.

In my example, I have some parameters that cannot be pickeled (they are c++ objects) and they take a lot of time to create.

Is there any way I can pass those parameters into the pool without having to make them serializable?

Answer (score 0):

[`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) allows to pass an initializer function which is executed every time a new worker process is spawned.

You can use this function to initialize you C++ objects. Each process will have its own copy.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

parameters = None

def initializer():
    global parameters

    parameters = initialize_cpluplus_objects()

def function():
    parameters.do_something()


pool = Pool(initializer=initializer_function)
pool.apply_async(function)
```